web-push требует каких-то настроек на стороне хоста?
Пробую сделать push-уведомления, но ни в какую не хочет отправляться, и предполагаю, что проблема со стороны хоста, возможно такое? Если да, то в чем именно может быть проблема?
Также на всякий случай прикладываю код
push.js (отправка push)


const webpush = require('web-push');

// VAPID keys should be generated only once.
const vapidKeys = {
    publicKey:
        "ключ",
    privateKey: "ключ",
};

webpush.setVapidDetails(
    'mailto:example@mtfdance.org',
    vapidKeys.publicKey,
    vapidKeys.privateKey
);
// This is the same output of calling JSON.stringify on a PushSubscription
const pushSubscription = {
    endpoint: process.argv[2],
    keys: {
        p256dh: process.argv[3],
        auth: process.argv[4]
    }
};
function sendNotification(pushSubscription, notificationTitle, notificationText) {
    const notificationPayload = {
        title: notificationTitle,
        body: notificationText,
        // Другие необязательные параметры уведомления
    };

    return webpush
        .sendNotification(
            pushSubscription,
            JSON.stringify(notificationPayload)
        )
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('Уведомление успешно отправлено:', notificationTitle + ' ' + notificationText + ' ' +JSON.stringify(result));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('Ошибка отправки уведомления:', JSON.stringify(err));
        });
}
const notificationTitle = "Название уведомления по умолчанию";
const notificationText = "Текст уведомления по умолчанию";
sendNotification(pushSubscription, notificationTitle, notificationText);



sw4.js (service-worker)


const VERSION = "v4";

log = (msg) => console.log(`${VERSION}:${msg}`);

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification
    const options = {
        body: "Buzz! Buzz!",
        icon: "https://i.sstatic.net/1rCh2.jpg?s=48&g=1",
        vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
        tag: "vibration-sample",
    }

    let promise = self.registration.showNotification('Push notification!', options);

    event.waitUntil(promise);
});



Получаю ответ о том, что уведомление было отправлено(Уведомление успешно отправлено:), но мне ничего не пришло
endpoint, p256dh, auth - всё корректное
result -
statusCode: 201,
  body: '',
  headers: {
    location: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/0:1714822492441112%e609af1cf9fd7ecd',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'x-xss-protection': '0',
    date: 'Sat, 04 May 2024 11:34:52 GMT',
    'content-length': '0',
    'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
    'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000'
  }

